# Is there a good way to move a rock?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

In Animal Crossing, I've got a Rock somewhere I would like to put a building.

I would love to move it elsewhere, but it seems I only have 2 choices. Destroy it, or not put the building there.

If I destroy it there I would straight up lose one of my rocks on my island, with seemingly no way to put in a new rock (like I could with trees) and Rocks are the source of a few precious ressources.

So is there a way to move a rock out of the way without just destroying it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, there's no way to just move a rock. You have to destroy it ...

But don't worry, rocks do respawn if destroyed.

Note that there's a 1 / day rock respawn limiter. If you break 2 rocks, you'll only respawn 1 on the next day.

Comment: Oh allright. So if you destroy a rock it will comeback, probably next day?

Comment: Yes, likely not in the same spot. Also, sometimes rocks get destroyed just by hitting them with your shovel but you can force the thing by eating a fruit and smacking it with the hammer.

Comment: Note that there's a 1 / day rock respawn limiter. If you break 2 rocks, you'll only respawn 1 on the next day.

Comment: A shovel can also break a rock if you’ve eaten a fruit.